# Add property to maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I have a Maven archetype project and want to make some further things configurable. I tried:

1. Putting `${servicelocatorhost}$` and `${servicelocatorport}` into my `.tomcatplugin` file.
2. Adding `.tomcatplugin` to the *filtered* files in the archetype metadata file.
3. Adding

   ```
   <requiredProperties>
     <requiredProperty key="servicelocatorhost">
       <defaultValue>localhost</defaultValue>
     </requiredProperty>
     <requiredProperty key="servicelocatorport">
       <defaultValue>2809</defaultValue>
     </requiredProperty>
   </requiredProperties>
   ```

to the archetype metadata file. When I build this, I get

```
Archetype IT 'basic' failed: Missing required properties in archetype.properties: servicelocatorhost, servicelocatorport
```

Until now I thought that the `archetype.properties` file is only for `create-from-project` but not building archetypes. Should I double the information for the properties and default values in such a file?

What exactly do I need to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When creating the archetype, there's also an integration test created for it. The values in the archetype.properties file are used when running the integration test (using the maven-invoker-plugin).

As an example: I have a simple archetype that filters a POM. In addition to GAV coordinates, I wanted the archetype user to provide the name of their Subversion repository and the application root directory so I could populate the `<scm>` block correctly. So I created variables `${scmRepo}`, `${applicationRootDir}`, and `${artifactId}` in the archetype-metadata.xml file:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="svnRepo" />
    <requiredProperty key="applicationRootDir" />
    <requiredProperty key="artifactId">
    ....
</requiredProperties>
```

then used them in the POM (`src/main/resouces/archetype-resources/pom.xml`):

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:https://host.company.com/svn/${svnRepo}/trunk/${applicationRootDir}/${artifactId}</connection>
</scm>
```

The last step is to provide default values in the archetype.properties file. This is only used when you as the developer build the archetype, not when your community *uses* the archetype to create a project. It allows you to ensure the archetype does what you want. So in my example the archetype.properties file contains

```
svnRepo=maven
applicationRootDir=basic
artifactId=test
```

In the same directory, I have a verify.groovy file containing code to verify that the archetype worked correctly:

```
def xmlFile = new File(basedir, "pomFileDir/pom.xml")
assert xmlFile.exists()

def project = new XmlSlurper().parse(xmlFile)
....
assert "scm:svn:https://host.company.com/svn/maven/trunk/basic/test" == project.scm.connection.text()
```

I learned this from [this blog post](https://www.luckyryan.com/2013/02/15/create-maven-archetype-from-existing-project/), this [archetype documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html), and my own knowledge of using the Maven invoker plugin.